# Doctrine MongoDB - Query on Document with multiple level of embedded document

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have some problems with embedding document with Doctrine MongoDB ODM and Symfony 2.

To expose the problem, I have the document product embedOne productInformation, and productInformation embedOne productInformationAddress.

To query, I use something like that :

```php
/**
 * @ODM\Document 
 **/
class product {
    /**
     * @ODM\EmbedOne(targetDocument="productInformation")
     **/
    protected $informations;
}

/**
 * @ODM\EmbeddedDocument 
 **/
class productInformations {
    /**
     * @ODM\EmbedOne(targetDocument="productInformationAddress")
     **/
    protected $address;

    /**
     * @ODM\Collection
     **/
    protected $attr1 = array();

    /**
     * @ODM\String
     **/
    protected $attr2
}

/**
 * @ODM\EmbeddedDocument 
 **/
class productInformationAddress {
    /** ... suff ... /*
}
```

When I query :

```php
class productRepository {
    public function fetchOne($id) {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder()
            ->field('id')->equals($id)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getSingleResult();
    }
}
```

But, I don't understand why I cannot get `$product->getInformations()->getAddress()`, that always return `null`...

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem with the code you posted, but it would probably be helpful to read through ODM's functional tests for nested, embedded documents. In [EmbeddedTest.php](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/blob/master/tests/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Tests/Functional/EmbeddedTest.php), the methods of interest would be anything that uses `EmbeddedTestLevel2`, which is equivalent to your `productInformationAddress` class, and `testRemoveAddDeepEmbedded()`.

Comment: thank you for the answer, in fact, the problem was simple... the cache... But, you're right and thank you for the link for the test.